# Uncaught C++ exception and minidump with call stack

Tags: c++, windows, exception, callstack, minidump

Is it possible to get a call stack from the point of throwing an exception, when the exception is uncaught and terminate handler is called? On windows.

I must mention, that I can not use debugger, I want to create a mini dump in the terminate handler, or at least write call stack in a file. Could you please provide some details how to get call stack in my situation?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Try to run program under debugger (e.g. gdb) and when it stopped see stack trace (command `bt` for gdb)

Comment: Is this information to add to the exception, or just for viewing in the debugger whilst debugging the application?

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/exception/set_terminate/

Comment: I must mention, that I can not use debugger, I want to create a mini dump in the terminate handler, or at least write call stack in a file. Could you please provide some details how to get call stack in my situation?